# Add connection to a database in visual studio that is already created on another computer

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015

We are a group working on a project with a database and on my computer I have done the connection to the database via Ado.net entity data model. Now the issue is that we are several people working on the same project (via github) but we are unsure on how to make the connection on the other computers.

I have shared the database by flash drive to the others but how do we connect them to the database as I have done.

If we do the same with Ado.net it will create the helper classes again and that is not what we want so how do we go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Just you need to restore your database to SQL Server.

2) Go to config file in your project root directory it might be web.config or app.config depending on your project type.

3) There would be a connectionstring Section created by ADO .Net DataModel.

4) Change "username", "Password" and "catalog" to those you specified in SQL Server when restoring the DB.